# How can I deserialize JSON to a Map<String, Object> member variable using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some JSON I would like to map to my `Box`object:

```
  {
      "created_date": "2015-11-11",
      "generation_date": "2015-11-12T20:35:00+0000",
      "values": {
          "MORNING": 13,
          "EVENING": 18,
          "NOON": 446,
          "NIGHT": "0.60.0"
      },
      "id": "12345"
  }
```

And my `Box` object looks like:

```
public class Box {
    @JsonProperty
    Map<String, Object> json;

    public Box() {
        // Blank
    }

    // Getter and setter for `json` field
}
```

This is the code I have:

```
Box box = null;
// `JSON_STRING` below refers to a string of the above JSON
metricsPacket = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_STRING, Box.class);
```

I keep getting this error:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "created_date" (class com.me.Box), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "json"])`

All of the examples I've found online are just deserializing JSON to a simple POJO with a handful of `String` or `int` member variables. How can I properly map my JSON to my `json` field and have it behave correctly?

I'd imagine that once this works `json.get("id")` would return `12345` while `json.get("values")` would return another `Map<String, Object>` (or `Map<String, String>`). I'm still new to using Jackson, so this also might not even be the right way to do what I want to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, addressing your problem. You are trying to de-serialize JSON to a class that doesn't have fields present in the JSON string, so it's failing to find those fields and returning the exception.

You could alternatively do the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(JSON_STRING, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
box.setJsonMap(map);
```

where box would have a setter to set the json map

Or you could add all the fields to your Box POJO and use [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to make this easier!

E.g. Json -> Object

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Box box = gson.fromJson(JSON_STRING, Box.class);
```

E.g. Object -> Json

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String str = gson.toJson(mBox); //mBox is some box object
```

GSON would populate all the fields within box to match the key, value pairs found in the JSON string. Ignore this if you don't want to do that but it is another alternative!

Comment: `TypeReference` with `import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;`

Comment: @lucas-crawford, you do not need to instantiate map if you are later setting it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an annotated argument to your constructor. For example,

```
public Box(@JsonProperty("json") Map<String, Object> json) {
    // TODO
}
```